# Are there existing standard/best-practices for authenticating an application AND a user to a REST API

Tags: rest

We're in the process of creating a REST API for access to a data store. This API will be used by various 3rd party mobile **applications**, whose permission to use the API we need to control. In addition, we need to control over the **user**s of each of these applications (a user may be able to use multiple applications).

So, for each call to our API we need to authenticate both that the **application**'s credentials are valid and also that the **user**'s are as well.

I can think of a few ways of doing this (two custom HTTP headers for example), but I wanted to ask whether there was a standard or common convention as it seems to me that this is a problem that would be fairly common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement such kind of authentication and authorization is to use OAuth 2.0 protocol . Your application needs to be an OAuth 2.0 server . The below link describes how google guards it APIs using OAuth 2.0 and how these APIs can be used.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: s/The best/One  This is a matter of opinion.

Comment: We've decided to go down the OAuth2 route. Thanks for the answer.